# Extends Array in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, oop

If I try to do this in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/):

```
class Test extends Array {
    constructor(items: number[]) {
        super(...items);
    }

    foo(): void { console.log('foo'); }
}

const t = new Test([]);
t.foo();
```

This does not work. `foo` is undefined. If I look at the generated code:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Test = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Test, _super);
    function Test(items) {
        return _super.apply(this, items) || this;
    }
    Test.prototype.foo = function () { console.log('foo'); };
    return Test;
}(Array));
var t = new Test([]);
t.foo();
```

The fuction returns the result of `_super.apply` instead of `this`. So I end up with an Array, not a Test inheriting from an Array. If I change this line

```
        return _super.apply(this, items) || this;
```

by

```
        _super.apply(this, items)
        return this;
```

It work as expected. Could it be a bug from Typescript due to the special nature of Array? Or is there something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Maybe because the `foo` method returns `void`, so there is nothing to console.log? Can you try just calling `t.foo()`? You're also missing the input argument to your `new Test()` constructor, I think...

Comment: Sorry, I modify my test code for the question to make it clearer and ended up messing it up. Fixed it.

Comment: See: https://blog.simontest.net/extend-array-with-typescript-965cc1134b3 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work